# How to encode only a part of URL

Tags: java

I have incomplete URL's which I am redirecting (don't have the full URL) like

```
a.jsp?id=269101|14000
```

and

```
b.jsp?action=in&id=239394|2000&inmethod=
```

I wanted to encode the pipe `"|"` char only, so I started with `java.net.URI` class but it asks for complete url.So I used URLEncoder but it encodes the entire url.

I know I can look for `|` in url and encode it directly but what would be the best approach?

Comment: Why is your String already put together but with parts unencoded? You should avoid doing that as that makes it very tricky to properly encode it. Use UrlEncoder to encode the values while they're still outside the final String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`String.replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-):

```
String myUrl = "b.jsp?action=in&id=239394|2000&inmethod=";
myUrl = myUrl.replace("|","%7C");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`URLEncoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) on each query parameter value that needs to be encoded.

```java
String url  = "b.jsp?action=in" +
                   "&id=" + URLEncoder.encode("239394|2000", StandardCharsets.UTF_8) +
                   "&inmethod=";
System.out.println(url); // prints: b.jsp?action=in&id=239394%7C2000&inmethod=
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the URLEncoder is the correct way to go. However you should do the encoding before you create your full url. using it on your full url will cause all special URL characters to be encoded. Which is not what you want here

Change your code to something like this

```
String url = "a.jsp?id=" + URLEncoder.encode("269101|14000",StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```